# Calculation of duration between hours

Tags: looker-studio

I would like to know how to calculate hours worked in Looker Studio for example, end time 01:09 subtracted from 23h59m is returning -22h40m whereas it should return 01h20m in duration;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8iEz.png)

(SUM(( CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA REAL DO FIM DE EXECUÇÃO - FORMATADA, "(.*):.*:.*") AS number ) * 3600 ) + ( CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA REAL DO FIM DE EXECUÇÃO - FORMATADA, ".*:(.*):.*") AS number ) * 60 ) + ( CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA REAL DO FIM DE EXECUÇÃO - FORMATADA, ".*:.*:(.*)") AS number ) ) )) - (SUM(( CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA DE INÍCIO DE EXECUÇÃO REAL - FORMATADA, "(.*):.*:.*") AS number ) * 3600 ) + ( CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA DE INÍCIO DE EXECUÇÃO REAL - FORMATADA, ".*:(.*):.*") AS number ) * 60 ) + ( CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA DE INÍCIO DE EXECUÇÃO REAL - FORMATADA, ".*:.*:(.*)") AS number ) ) ))

Answer (score 0):

I added a conditional statement that adds 86400 to the end time seconds if the end time is earlier than the start time, which would indicate that the time period crosses midnight

```
SUM(
  IF(
    CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA REAL DO FIM DE EXECUÇÃO - FORMATADA, "(.):.:.") AS number ) * 3600 +
    CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA REAL DO FIM DE EXECUÇÃO - FORMATADA, ".:(.):.") AS number ) * 60 +
    CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA REAL DO FIM DE EXECUÇÃO - FORMATADA, ".:.:(.)") AS number )
    <
    CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA DE INÍCIO DE EXECUÇÃO REAL - FORMATADA, "(.):.:.") AS number ) * 3600 +
    CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA DE INÍCIO DE EXECUÇÃO REAL - FORMATADA, ".:(.):.") AS number ) * 60 +
    CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA DE INÍCIO DE EXECUÇÃO REAL - FORMATADA, ".:.:(.)") AS number ),
    86400,
    0
  )
  +
  (CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA REAL DO FIM DE EXECUÇÃO - FORMATADA, "(.):.:.") AS number ) * 3600) +
  (CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA REAL DO FIM DE EXECUÇÃO - FORMATADA, ".:(.):.") AS number ) * 60) +
  (CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA REAL DO FIM DE EXECUÇÃO - FORMATADA, ".:.:(.)") AS number ))
)
-
SUM(
  (CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA DE INÍCIO DE EXECUÇÃO REAL - FORMATADA, "(.):.:.") AS number ) * 3600) +
  (CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA DE INÍCIO DE EXECUÇÃO REAL - FORMATADA, ".:(.):.") AS number ) * 60) +
  (CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(HORA DE INÍCIO DE EXECUÇÃO REAL - FORMATADA, ".:.:(.)") AS number ))
)
```